# Doctrine QueryBuilder - add PARTITION selection in clause FROM

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a table "actions" with partitions

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (MONTH(`created_at`)) (
        PARTITION `m1` VALUES LESS THAN (2),
        PARTITION `m2` VALUES LESS THAN (3),
        PARTITION `m3` VALUES LESS THAN (4),
        PARTITION `m4` VALUES LESS THAN (5),
        PARTITION `m5` VALUES LESS THAN (6),
        PARTITION `m6` VALUES LESS THAN (7),
        PARTITION `m7` VALUES LESS THAN (8),
        PARTITION `m8` VALUES LESS THAN (9),
        PARTITION `m9` VALUES LESS THAN (10),
        PARTITION `m10` VALUES LESS THAN (11),
        PARTITION `m11` VALUES LESS THAN (12),
        PARTITION `m12` VALUES LESS THAN (13)
        );
```

I want to select partitions in clause FROM:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM actions PARTITION (m6, m7) as t1
WHERE t1.created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
```

(It is the MySql)

but I don't now how that add to Doctrine QueryBuilder

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine does not support that in query builder. You either have to write [native SQL](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/native-sql.html) or create [custom DQL function](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html).

Comment: only-link answers are strongly descouraged (ex because the link could be removed or changed in the future). So you should add the essential parts needed to answer the OP question.

Comment: I tried to create custom function, but that function doesn't worn in clause FROM. ANd now I try to use native SQL.

Answer (score 0):

only 2 things in doctrine can hook into the `FROM` part - [AST walker and Output walker](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/cookbook/dql-custom-walkers.html). custom functions cannot.

imho in this case the best approach would be overriding `SqlWalker::walkFromClause()` with conjuction of custom query hint.